# Comparing 2 Sharepoint lists using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-list, powerapp, power-automate

I wanted to compare two sharepoint lists. one is forecasted expense against each resource for a particular month and other sharepoint list is the actual expenses that has come. The two sharepoint lists have same fields and column types.here, I want to check if there is any expense that has come which was not forecasted for the resource for that month. Also, want to show the Actual, forecast and the difference in Powerapp. Does anyone has any idea how can this be done? any kind of assistance is appreciated.

Is this how the flow would look like to update the 3rd list? Do I need to add any filter Query in get items?[image]

Comment: Looks like you need a third list to store the Actual, Forcast, and the Difference and then PowerApps can show data from this third list. Using MS FLow/Power Automate, you can compare values in two list and update then add/update the 3rd list. What is the common data element linking the forecast and actual expense lists?

Comment: @MatiurRahman Thank you for your response. :) Resource Name, Month and Year should be the common fields between the two lists.Is this how the flow would look like? Attached the flow screenshot in the mail question.

Comment: You're getting closer. In the [Update], which ID you're using. Also, I don't see any logic to determine the difference between the forecast and actual before updating the third list. If you can wait, I can create an example later today

Comment: Thank you @MatiurRahman. Yes, there is one more thing - a resource can have more than one expense line item for the same month. So, I wanted to have the total actual expense of the resource for the month compared to the total forecasted expense of the resource for the month.

Comment: I think, that can be handled. But first, let see whether the sample I just posted will work for you. It it works then we will look into the additional condition. It's very late in the night  here, so I'm logging off for now. Will check back in the morning.

Comment: Thank you so much, @MatiurRahman :) Yes, I am trying the solution you showed. will let you know if it worked for me. :) Good night!

Answer (score 0):

Since the two lists are pretty similar, for my test example, I'm adding a Number column called [ForcastMerged] and a Calculated column called [Difference] in ExpenseActual List.

The formula(which can be adjusted)for [Difference] is:

```
=IF(AND(ActualAmount<>0,ForecastMerged<>0),ActualAmount-ForecastMerged,0)
```

**See the MS Flow screenshots and explanation below**

[image]

**Expression for Set Variables**

```
Extracted from the current item of the [Apply to each]
varYear:
int(items('Apply_to_each')?['Year'])

varMonth:
int(items('Apply_to_each')?['Month'])

varForecastAmount:
items('Apply_to_each')?['ForecastAmount']

ID being extracted from [Get Items - Actual Expense].
varActualExpenseID:
if(equals(length(outputs('Get_items_-_Actual_Expense')?['body/value']), 0), 0,first(outputs('Get_items_-_Actual_Expense')?['body/value'])['ID'])
```

**Detail 1**

[image]

**Detail 2**

[image]

**ExpenseForcast and ExpenseActual Lists**

[image]

[image]

Should you have any questions, let me know.